# get all strings within an equal reference with explode

Tags: php

I would like to get all the strings within a specific reference. example:

```
$string = '<abc>A1</abc><bcd>B1</bcd><abc>A2</abc><bcd>B2</bcd><abc>A3</abc>';
```

I would like to get all the elements inside Tags `<abc>`, `</ abc>`, listing for example A1 A2 A3.

I tried to use explode like this:

```
$string = '<abc>A1</abc><bcd>B1</bcd><abc>A2</abc><bcd>B2</bcd><abc>A3</abc>';
$take = explode('<abc>', $string);
foreach ($take as $value) {
$take = explode('</abc>',$value);
```

It returned: array array array array

Comment: PLEASE DO NOT YELL!

Comment: Your strings are in those arrays. `print_r($take);`

Comment: Return: Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => A1 [1] => B1 ) Array ( [0] => A2 [1] => B2 ) Array ( [0] => A3 [1] => )

I would like to get all the elements inside Tags <abc>, </ abc>, listing for example A1 A2 A3.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression

```
$string = '<abc>A1</abc><bcd>B1</bcd><abc>A2</abc><bcd>B2</bcd><abc>A3</abc>';
preg_match_all('/<abc>(.*?)<\/abc>/s', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

explode function returns an array. Try this code.

```
$string = '<abc>A1</abc><bcd>B1</bcd><abc>A2</abc><bcd>B2</bcd><abc>A3</abc>';
$take = explode('<abc>', $string);
foreach ($take as $value) {
$take = explode('</abc>',$value);
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($take);
}
```